# Array de valores únicos com foreach

Tags: php, array, laravel, foreach

Tenho o seguinte `foreach` para pegar o id dos aparelhos que foram utilizados em cada setor:

```
@foreach($relatorio->Empresa->SetorEmpresa as $setor)
   {{ $collection[] = $setor->SetorEmpresaEdificacao->id_aparelho_ruido }}
@endforeach
```

O problema é que quando 2 setores foram medidos com o mesmo aparelho,  recebo esse valor 2 vezes. Como eu faço para isso não acontecer?

Estou recebendo assim:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 1
  2 => 2
]
```

Preciso receber assim, sem repetir:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 2
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Você já tentou o `array_unique`? Ele recebe o argumento `array` e retorna um novo array sem valores duplicados.

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "verde", "vermelho", "b" => "verde", "azul", "vermelho");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?>
```

O exemplo acima irá imprimir:

```
Array
(
    [a] => verde
    [0] => vermelho
    [1] => azul

)
```

Fonte: php.net

Comment: até li sobre esse array_unique, mas não consegui aplicar. Aplicando dessa forma não funciona, pois eu não passo o array ali, e sim um inteiro.

Comment: Como está essa array? Onde ela está sendo definida?

Comment: ela é criada ali msm no foreach. $collection[] = ...

Comment: consegui... coloquei $collection = array_unique($collection) depois do foreach

Comment: Boa man, isso ai!

Answer (score 0):

Cara, se é só o valor que você precisa, você pode definir os índices do seu array com os valores de id's recebidos.
O php sobrescreve todos os índices que forem iguais, assim você só terá um único índice que representa seus id's de aparelhos.

```
@foreach($relatorio->Empresa->SetorEmpresa as $setor)
   {{ $collection[$setor->SetorEmpresaEdificacao->id_aparelho_ruido] = $setor->SetorEmpresaEdificacao->id_aparelho_ruido }}
@endforeach
```